# VBA for regional settings

Tags: vba, regional

is there a VBA code to change regional settings as needed for Excel? I have ½ of my excel files that use date format 01/25/2020 and other half uses 1.1.2020 and its really frustrating to work with these. I need a simple way to switch regional settings as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The regional settings are fetched from Windows.

Your only option is to modify the *format* applied to the cells in question. You could create a macro to run through the cells and ranges that have a date format and modify the format to match your preference.